# Python error u'the label [-1] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python

When iterating through a pandas dataframe using an if statement to check conditions in one column among current and previous rows, like this:

```
    for i,row in DF.iterrows():
        if row['column1'] == DF.loc[i-1, 'column1']):
```

The **u'the label [-1] is not in the [index]'** error is produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the indexing starts with 0 in DF and when you are doing `DF.loc[i-1, 'column1'])` , its actually checking for the index -1 which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you Sanchit. I was going to post the answer but in all fairness, I'll recognize your response as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of digging in this community and the internet, realized the condition throws an error when the condition is met in the first row [row=0] because the code is trying to access row -1.

Comment: You realise instead of looping and then indexing, you can use `df.column1 == df.column1.shift(1)` and work with that?

Comment: @JonClementsthank you for your comment, shift(1) would allow me to match to the next row, which in theory should be the same, but in this case the business logic requires matching to previous instead.

Comment: Then use `shift(-1)` :)